# Determinant of $X=\begin{pmatrix} A & B & 0 \\ C & D & I_{n-l} \\ 0 & I_{n-l} & 0 \end{pmatrix}$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Say we have a matrix $$X=\begin{pmatrix}
A & B & 0 \\
C & D & I_{n-l} \\
0 & I_{n-l} & 0
\end{pmatrix}$$
With $A, B, C, D$ being of size $l\times l$,$l\times (n-l)$, $(n-l)\times l$, $(n-l)\times (n-l)$ resp.

Suppose $A$ is non-singular. My goal is to show that $X$ is non-singular (I've found that actually $\det(X)=\pm \det(A)$).

I've looked at some identities and found Schurs determinant formula. It states that
$$\det(X)=\det(A)\det(\begin{pmatrix}
D & I_{n-l} \\
I_{n-l} & 0
\end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix}
C \\
0
\end{pmatrix}A^{-1}\begin{pmatrix}
B & 0
\end{pmatrix})=\det(A)\det(\begin{pmatrix}
D-CA^{-1}B & I_{n-l} \\
I_{n-l} & 0
\end{pmatrix})$$
I could maybe use Schurs formula again, however I'm not sure whether $D-CA^{-1}B$ is non-singular.

I've also tried looking wheter $D-CA^{-1}B=0$, since then of course $\det(X)=\pm \det(A)$.

Comment: Your conclusion and condition are contradicting. If $X$ is non-singular, then $X$ has rank $2n - l > l$.

Comment: My bad. I mixed a couple of things. $X$ doesn't have rank $l$.

Comment: You can eliminate blocks $B, C, D$ by just using the two identity matrices $I_{(n - l)}$ as pivot, so that $X$ is equivalent to $\begin{pmatrix} A & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & I_{(n - l)} \\ 0 & I_{(n - l)} & 0 \end{pmatrix}$, which is apparently non-singular.

Comment: Thank you! That seems to work together with Schurs formula.

Comment: what @Zhanxiong is telling you is there is no need for Schur complements, etc.  You can reduce $X$ to $\begin{pmatrix} A & \mathbf 0  \\ \mathbf  0 & Q  \end{pmatrix}$ purely by left and right multiplication of type 1 elementary matrices (each of which has determinant of one); $Q= \begin{pmatrix} \mathbf 0 & I_{(n - l)} \\ I_{(n - l)}& \mathbf 0   \end{pmatrix}$  and of course $Q^TQ =I \implies \det\big(Q\big) \in \{-1,+1\}$ and by basic properties of block-diagonal matrices $\det\left(\begin{pmatrix} A & \mathbf 0  \\ \mathbf  0 & Q  \end{pmatrix}\right)= \det(A)\cdot \det(Q)= \pm \det(A)$